# display duplicates according to count?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have 2 tables books and bkdates I want to get duplicates according to count
books
id|name|edno
1|book1|1
2|book2|2
3|book1|1
4|book2|2
5|book1|1
6|book3|3

---

bkdates
edno|year
1|1980
2|1990
1|1980
1|1988
2|1991
2|1990
1|1980
3|2003

---

expected output 
edno|year|count
1|1980|3
1|1988|1
2|1990|2
2|1991|1
any help??!

Comment: [This should be helpful](https://google.com/search?q=mysql+tutorial).

Comment: If you don't have any code, yet, start your research here: [MySQL COUNT() function with group by](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php). If you can't get that to work, edit your question and include your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Select edno, year, COUNT(edno) from bkdates group by year

Comment: someone changed question?

Comment: I want to get duplicates books withe different date. if books one(have 2 dates) I want to display it